# Will clustering Oracle Database into multiple PCs enhance performance?

Tags: database, oracle11g, cluster-computing, clustered-index

There are several packages in my oracle DBMS which sometimes fails to complete the task of takes more than 6 to 7 hours to complete the task even if the procedures and packages are error free.

This only occurs when multiple clients try to run different packages from their system into a server pc which contains the database at same time like the picture shown.

There are 20 client systems and 1 single server PC in my office.

[image: Like this]

I am asking if I use 2 or more pcs to cluster my oracle db will that be helpful to enhance performance i.e. will it reduce package run time and will it reduce chances of failing package run ?

Comment: I suggest to identify why the packages run slowly first instead of trying out any solutions. Do you have any AWR, ADDM reports or root cause analysis details that you can share?

Comment: Thanks ArtBajji for your response. I wish could share the information you have desired. But there are some internal restrictions i have to follow and for which i can not do anything. I will be thankful if you kindly tell me whether clustering will solve the problem ?

Comment: You have to figure out what the actual problem is before you can try to evaluate any specific solution. Which is what ArtBaji was saying I think, really. There may be code or schema changes that would help, or DB settings, or PC changes (adding RAM say), or... well, lots of things. But without knowing what is actually happening you could easily make things worse by making random changes.

Comment: What does it mean "...fails to complete the task..."? How it fails? What is the error?